# Scarlet WebSocket @Receive never gets triggered

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, websocket

I have integrated Scarlet WebSockets in my application.
Using Koin DI i provide the FlowSocketApi as below

```
 single {
        return@single AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(androidApplication())
    }

    single {
        return@single Scarlet.Builder()
            .webSocketFactory(get<OkHttpClient>().newWebSocketFactory(Wss))
            .lifecycle(get())  
            .backoffStrategy(LinearBackoffStrategy(10000))
            .addMessageAdapterFactory(GsonMessageAdapter.Factory(get()))
            .addStreamAdapterFactory(CoroutinesStreamAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(FlowSocketApi::class.java)
    }
```

and the Api interface is

```
interface FlowSocketApi {

    @Receive
    fun observeEvents(): ReceiveChannel<WebSocket.Event>

    @Send
    fun send(message: Any): Boolean

    @Receive
    fun observeApiMessage(): ReceiveChannel<FlowSocketResponse>

}
```

I also have a FlowSocketService that implements the above functions.
So when i want to take the results although the `observeEvents` and the `send` methods work properly the `observerApiMessage` never gets triggered when the server sends an answer to the send.

```
// Works fine
flowSocketService.observeEvents().consumeAsFlow().asLiveData().observeForever {
            it?.let {
                println(it)
            }
        }


// Does not work
flowSocketService.observeApiMessage().consumeAsFlow().asLiveData().observeForever {
            it?.let {
                println("flowMessagesObserver result")
                println(it)
            } ?: run {
                println("flowMessagesObserver null")
            }
        }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode the message manually from `observeEvents()`:

`Json.decodeFromString<YourApiMessagePOJO>((it.message as Message.Text).value)`

if this is the location of the error, the logcat will indicate what happened.